How thousands of users receive the same messages published to AWS SNS Topic
I published a few messages to my AWS SNS topic. Then, I added some code to my .NET Console App to receive the messages. The problem is I can never receive 3 messages at once. Here is my code in .NET Console App:
var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("someKey", "someKey");
sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
 var receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest
 {
     QueueUrl = queueUrl,
     MaxNumberOfMessages = 10,
     WaitTimeSeconds = 20 // Long polling for 20 seconds
 };

 var response = await sqsClient.ReceiveMessageAsync(receiveMessageRequest);


The settings of my queue are: Type Standard, Visibility Timeout 30 seconds. When I polled the messages in AWS Console, I can see all three messages. But in the response, I can only see a part of it. The first time running the app, I got the first message. The second time I got 2 other messages.
Then I updated the settings to Visibility Timeout 0 second, I got 10 messages at once (they are duplicated) which is strange.
How do I receive all three and is it possible if I have many users using the same app and are able to see the messages at the same time (because I read somewhere that there will be some gaps between polling the messages from the same queue)?

You are publishing a message to SNS, but you are polling them via SQS. Please describe how you have integrated SNS and SQS. At this time there is not enough detail in your question to understand what you are doing.

When you use the Amazon SQS console to 'poll' messages, they are actually being accessed via the ReceiveMessage API call. This will trigger the visibility timeout on those messages, so they are not available for receiving until the timeout expires. This is shown by the fact that setting the visibility timeout to zero resulted in more messages being available.
If you want your code to operate in 'normal' conditions, I recommend you do not do not use the console to view message queues while your code is running.
Also, from ReceiveMessage - Amazon Simple Queue Service:

Short poll is the default behavior where a weighted random set of machines is sampled on a ReceiveMessage call. Thus, only the messages on the sampled machines are returned. If the number of messages in the queue is small (fewer than 1,000), you most likely get fewer messages than you requested per ReceiveMessage call. If the number of messages in the queue is extremely small, you might not receive any messages in a particular ReceiveMessage response. If this happens, repeat the request.

Therefore, you won't necessarily always be given the full number of messages requested, depending upon how the messages are distributed over the Amazon SQS servers. See also: Basic Amazon SQS architecture - Amazon Simple Queue Service

Thanks John for the response. So, is there any alternative I can use to get all the messages published to the topic? I know that I can subscribe to them via HTTP endpoint but that would require using a database to store the messages and a GET API to get the messages. So I haven't been able to find any other solution rather than SQS but it doesn't seem appropriate if I have a large number of users of the same app.

If you wan to get all messages, then call ReceiveMessage() in a loop until there are no messages returned.
